# how to get all rules for a specific IPaddress

Tags: iptables

Is there any known way how to get all iptables rules ipsets and so on which are valid for an specific IPaddress so that I can see missing ones with a simple view ?

Comment: Hello. I do not understand your question. What is it you want to do? What version of Ubuntu is this for?

Comment: try "iptables -S | grep <IP>"

Comment: with iptables -S | grep <IP> you do not catch the rules which handling a ip range I guess and how about ipset ?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 20.04 - 21.10 all systems have the same.
my list of rules currently  containing several different chains. some of them for some tcp ports and the chain itself containing just accept for ips . So something should create a list of lines with all rules for one specific ip or group of source and dest.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do what you want. By adding a lot of debug logging rules to your iptables rule set your could get it logged.

Comment: hmm but therefore the rules have to be touched ... so it will take a while.
May I go the way to check every rule shown with -S if either my ip matches or my ip matches the ip range and show the result. Tricky but ... lets see

Answer (score 0):

You can check each iptables chain (input, forward and output) with this command:

- `sudo iptables -nL | grep <IP you are looking for>`

Also, with this you will notice the policy DROP or ACCEPT. Depending on your default configuration.

[image]